# What's the meaning of the dot in .NET struct names in MS docs?

Tags: .net, .net-core

Many structs in the [System.Collections.Generic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic?view=net-5.0#structs) namespace are identified by `{className}.{structName}`.

What's the reasoning for this syntax? What's special about the "dot syntax"?

Comment: They are [nested types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/nested-types)

Comment: e.g. [`SortedSet<T>.Enumerator`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic/SortedSet.cs#L1896) in the source.

Comment: Part of the reasoning is so that they can inherit the various generic parameters of the parent class, without having to redeclare them. It also prevents namespace clutter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means they're nested within the class. For example:

```cs
public class OuterClass
{
    public class NestedClass
    {
    }
}
```

Here `NestedClass` would be documented as `OuterClass.NestedClass`, although the full name as reported by reflection would be `OuterClass+NestedClass`.

Comment: Ah, it's as simple as that. I wasn't aware of the notation they appeared in in the docs. I would have expected them to be listed nested-wise or similar, not as a sibling. Thank you all for enlightening me.